# .Range("A" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(0).textContent error

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

[Snapshot on the table i would like to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGOhS.png) I would like to import financial statement from the WSJ. I have designed a code(below) but it does not seem to be working. When I run it, I get “run time error 91 object variable or with block variable not set.” Upon clicking debugging, the asteriked line is highlighted yellow.

```
Can anyone assist?

Here is the code I wrote

Sub finanacialdata()
Dim ieobj As InternetExplorer
Dim htmlele As IHTMLElement
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
Set ieobj = New InternetExplorer
ieobj.Visible = True
ieobj.navigate ""https://www.wsj.com/market-data/quotes/GOL/financials/annual/balance-sheet
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00.00.10")

For Each htmlele In ie.obj.document.getElementsByClassName("zonedmodule")(0).getElementBytagname("tr")
    With ActiveSheet
         *.Range("A" & i).Value = htmlele.Children(0).textContent*
         .Range("B" & i).Value = htmlele.Children(1).textContent
         .Range("C" & i).Value = htmlele.Children(2).textContent
         .Range("D" & i).Value = htmlele.Children(3).textContent
         .Range("E" & i).Value = htmlele.Children(4).textContent
         .Range("F" & i).Value = htmlele.Children(5).textContent
    End With
    i = i + 1
    Next htmlele
End Sub

Thank you
```

Comment: I try to check the VBA code and the source code of the WSJ site. From the VBA code, it looks like you want to access the text data receded in the children of TR tags of the first element that has the class name 'zonedmodule'. If we refer to the source code using the developer tools then you can notice that the first element that has the class name 'zonedmodule' is empty. Due to this reason, you will not get any data in the Excel sheet. If you can show the snapshot of the data that you want to access from the site then we can try to provide some code examples for that.

Comment: Dear Deepak, thank you very much for your reply. I had added the snapshot of that data, in my original post,  i would like to import. It is an Balance sheet of the GOL airlines. Once again thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Below sample code can help you to fetch the table data for **Assets**.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub demo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, clipboard As Object
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://your_site_address_here"  'please modify site address here...

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
     
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1) = "Assets"
            clipboard.SetText IE.document.getElementsByClassName("cr_dataTable")(0).outerHTML
            clipboard.PutInClipboard
       
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1).PasteSpecial
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

**Note:** You just need to add your site address in this sample code.

Test result:

[image]

Further, you can modify this code example based on your requirements. Let us know if you have any further questions regarding this issue.

Thanks for your understanding.